# ValueError: An operation has 'None' for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient difined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I keep getting this error with the following code

```
config_path = 'E:/chinese_roberta_wwm_large_ext_L-24_H-1024_A-16/bert_config.json'
checkpoint_path = 'E:/chinese_roberta_wwm_large_ext_L-24_H-1024_A-16/bert_model.ckpt'
dict_path = 'E:/chinese_roberta_wwm_large_ext_L-24_H-1024_A-16/vocab.txt'

# 将词表中的词编号转换为字典
token_dict = {}
with codecs.open(dict_path, 'r', 'utf8') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        token = line.strip()
        token_dict[token] = len(token_dict)


# 重写tokenizer
class OurTokenizer(Tokenizer):
    def _tokenize(self, text):
        R = []
        for c in text:
            if c in self._token_dict:
                R.append(c)
            elif self._is_space(c):
                R.append('[unused1]')  # 用[unused1]来表示空格类字符
            else:
                R.append('[UNK]')  # 不在列表的字符用[UNK]表示
        return R


tokenizer = OurTokenizer(token_dict)


# 让每条文本的长度相同，用0填充
def seq_padding(X, padding=0):
    L = [len(x) for x in X]
    ML = max(L)
    return np.array([
        np.concatenate([x, [padding] * (ML - len(x))]) if len(x) < ML else x for x in X
    ])

def seq_padding_2(X, padding=0):
    L = [x.shape[0] for x in X]
    ML = max(L)

    results = []
    for x in X:

        if x.shape[0] < ML:
            r = np.array([0] * 21128)
            x_1 = list(x)
            for i in range((ML-x.shape[0])):
                x_1.append(r)
            results.append(np.array(x_1))
        else:
            results.append(x)

    return np.array(results)




# data_generator只是一种为了节约内存的数据方式
class data_generator:
    def __init__(self, data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True):
        self.data = data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.steps = len(self.data) // self.batch_size
        if len(self.data) % self.batch_size != 0:
            self.steps += 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self.steps

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            idxs = list(range(len(self.data)))

            if self.shuffle:
                np.random.shuffle(idxs)

            X1, X2, Y = [], [], []
            for i in idxs:
                d = self.data[i]
                text = d[0][:maxlen]
                x1, x2 = tokenizer.encode(first=text)
                y = d[1]

                X1.append(x1)
                X2.append(x2)
                Y.append(y)

                if len(X1) == self.batch_size or i == idxs[-1]:
                    X1 = seq_padding(X1)
                    X2 = seq_padding(X2)
                    Y = seq_padding_2(Y)

                    yield [X1, X2], Y
                    [X1, X2, Y] = [], [], []


# calculate sparse categorical accuracy
def acc_top2(y_true, y_pred):
    return sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)


# bert模型设置
def build_corrector():
    bert_model_1 = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(config_path, checkpoint_path, seq_len=None)  # load pretrain bert model
    for l in bert_model_1.layers:
        l.trainable = True

    x1_in = Input(shape=(None,))
    x2_in = Input(shape=(None,))

    x1 = bert_model_1([x1_in, x2_in])
    x3 = keras.layers.GRU(maxlen)(x1)

    bert_model_2 = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(config_path, checkpoint_path, seq_len=None, training=True)  # load pretrain bert model
    for l in bert_model_2.layers:
        l.trainable = True

    x2 = bert_model_2([x1_in, x2_in, x3])[0]
    model = Model([x1_in, x2_in], x2)
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(1e-5))
    return model


DATA_LIST = []
for data_row in train_df.iloc[:].itertuples():
    DATA_LIST.append((data_row.testing_sentence, to_categorical(tokenizer.encode(data_row.correct_sentence)[0], 21128)))
DATA_LIST = np.array(DATA_LIST)

DATA_LIST_TEST = []
for data_row in train_df.iloc[:].itertuples():
    DATA_LIST_TEST.append((data_row.testing_sentence, to_categorical(tokenizer.encode(data_row.correct_sentence)[0], 21128)))
DATA_LIST_TEST = np.array(DATA_LIST_TEST)

#print(DATA_LIST)
#print(DATA_LIST_TEST)

# 交叉验证训练和测试模型
def run_cv(nfold, data, data_labels, data_test):
    kf = KFold(n_splits=nfold, shuffle=True, random_state=520).split(data)
    train_model_pred = np.zeros((len(data), 2))
    test_model_pred = np.zeros((len(data_test), 2))

    for i, (train_fold, test_fold) in enumerate(kf):
        X_train, X_valid, = data[train_fold, :], data[test_fold, :]

        model = build_corrector()
        #early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=3)  # 早停法，防止过拟合
        plateau = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_acc", verbose=1, mode='max', factor=0.5,
                                    patience=2)  # 当评价指标不在提升时，减少学习率
        checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('./bert_dump/' + str(i) + '.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=2,
                                     save_best_only=True, mode='max', save_weights_only=True)  # 保存最好的模型

        train_D = data_generator(X_train, shuffle=True)
        valid_D = data_generator(X_valid, shuffle=True)
        test_D = data_generator(data_test, shuffle=False)
        # 模型训练
        model.fit_generator(
            train_D.__iter__(),
            steps_per_epoch=len(train_D),
            epochs=5,
            validation_data=valid_D.__iter__(),
            validation_steps=len(valid_D),
            callbacks=[plateau, checkpoint],
        )

        # model.load_weights('./bert_dump/' + str(i) + '.hdf5')

        # return model
        train_model_pred[test_fold, :] = model.predict_generator(valid_D.__iter__(), steps=len(valid_D), verbose=1)
        test_model_pred += model.predict_generator(test_D.__iter__(), steps=len(test_D), verbose=1)

        del model
        gc.collect()  # 清理内存
        K.clear_session()  # clear_session就是清除一个session
        # break

    return train_model_pred, test_model_pred

data_generator(DATA_LIST, shuffle=True).__iter__().__next__()
train_model_pred, test_model_pred = run_cv(2, DATA_LIST, None, DATA_LIST_TEST)

test_pred = [np.argmax(x) for x in test_model_pred]
```

the error traceback is as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/PycharmProjects/keras_bert/venv/ks.py", line 208, in <module>
    train_model_pred, test_model_pred = run_cv(2, DATA_LIST, None, DATA_LIST_TEST)
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/PycharmProjects/keras_bert/venv/ks.py", line 191, in run_cv
    callbacks=[plateau, checkpoint],
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 42, in fit_generator
    model._make_train_function()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 316, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 504, in get_updates
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 93, in get_gradients
    raise ValueError('An operation has `None` for gradient. '
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

the bert model package I am using is keras-bert. I was trying to do the soft-masked bert on my own. When I was working on seq2seq with hard mask, i also got the same error.
I need some helps on this error, because as far as I know the keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy is differentiable.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full error traceback.

Comment: sorry, will do that as soon as possible